# Does Python MySQL have issues inserting 2 new columns via 2 variables?

Tags: python, mysql

So I am making a Python password manager with MySQL and I ran into an issue. I didn't get any error messages, but when I entered in some records, I tried to see them using `SELECT * FROM passwords` but the records weren't inserted. Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
import time
# SETS UP SQL
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="[redacted]",
    database="passwords"
)

c = mydb.cursor()
# DEFINES MODE FUNCTIONS
def seeAll():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM passwords")
    for x in c:
        print(x)

def insert():
    serv = str(input("PLEASE ENTER THE SITE OF THE PASSWORD YOU WOULD LIKE TO RECORD: "))
    pw = str(input("PLEASE ENTER THE PASSWORD YOU WOULD LIKE TO RECORD: "))
    sql = "INSERT INTO passwords (service, passwords) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    c.execute(serv, pw, sql)
    mydb.commit()
    seechange = str(input("RECORD INSERTED, WOULD YOU LIKE TO SEE CHANGES (y/n): "))
    if seechange == "y":
        print("OK, RETRIEVING TABLE...")
        time.sleep(3)
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM passwords")
        for x in c:
            print(x)
    else:
        print("OK")
# ------------------------------------------- #
print("WELCOME TO MR. MANAGER")
# SET PASSWORD TO USE THE MANAGER
metapass = str(input("PLEASE ENTER PASSWORD: "))
if metapass != "[redacted]":
    print("INCORRECT  PASSWORD, TRY AGAIN.")
# MODE ENTERING SYSTEM
else:
    print("MODES: 1. INSERT PASSWORD, 2. RETURN PASSWORD, 3. SEE ALL.")
    mode = int(input("PLEASE ENTER MODE AS INTEGER: "))
if mode < 1:
    print("INVALID MODE, TRY AGAIN.")
elif mode > 3:
    print("INVALID MODE, TRY AGAIN.")
# CALLS FUNCTION BASED ON MODE
if mode == 1:
    insert()
if mode == 2:
    returnPW()
if mode == 3:
    seeAll()
```

By the way, I of course didn't put the passwords as [redacted], just didn't want to show my password on the internet ;).
But I was wondering if the issue stemmed from me trying to insert via multiple variables? Thanks in advance!
PS: Yes I used a pseudo loading wait HAHA. It just looks cooler.

Answer (score 1):

The `cursor.execute` function expects the data to be added to be passed in via the second parameter, either using a tuple or a dictionary.

Change

```
c.execute(serv, pw, sql)
```

to

```
c.execute(serv, (pw, sql))
```